# Setup Notepad++ editor in git Bash Console and Need some Reason

Tags: git, notepad++

I want to set up Notepad++ editor for my Git Bash as my default editor is vi.

So, I have used this git config command.

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

I tried to find out the reason why we have to use

```
-multiInst
-notabbar
-nosession
-noPlugin
```

for my git Notepad++ editor but didn't get it. I just want to know about this config. If this question is repeated then give me the answered link and I'll delete my post for better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can remove the arguments, it is not recommended. Notepad++ would work but there are a few things may annoy you.

See [the manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/command-prompt/) for more information.

- `multiInst` is used so that notepad++ starts in a new window if it is already started. Without that argument, it would open a new tab and you will need to close notepad++ in order to make the commit.
- `notabbar` just removes the tab bar as you don't need it.
- `nosession` does not open previously opened files in notepad++ when editing the commit message.
- `noplugin` starts notepad++ without plugins. This makes it faster to start.

Comment: I just googled `notepad++ documentation parameters`.